# Conditionally applying css style in react spa app

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webpack

I have a project where I am trying to apply different CSS styles for different layouts (which I am detecting by the URL, basically we have two different domain names). In the `webpack.config` file, I have excluded the style sheet used for the 2nd layout as it was loading all the CSS and putting it all in a single file during the build (which overrides the body color set for layout 1 with layout 2). But after excluding that particular CSS file it was not adding the style sheet back when viewing the 2nd website. Its a react app, and I am using an if condition to apply the style:

`index.js` file:

```
if (window.location.hostname.includes("website2")) {
  require("./assets/css/style1.css");
  require("./assets/css/style2.css");
} else {
  require("./assets/css/style1.css");
}
```

`webpack.config`

```
module: {
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /\style2.css$/,
  ....
}
```

I am new to webpack, so I am not sure if I should exclude the CSS file in this manner.

Comment: Does the webpack run before getting deployed or after? This happens statically. So, if you run the webpack build before deployment to the two domains, this condition will not be valid. For the hostname thing, I would prefer you checking this: [Accessing the URL hostname from React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37330947).

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is a development / build tools. It only compiles source files. So your code won't work in runtime.

You should set a root css class as namespace/theme in each css file, then just change class name in `body` tag.

```css
// note: scss styles

.style1 {
 // style theme 1
}

.style2 {
 // style theme 2
}
```

```html
if (window.location.hostname.includes("website2")) {
  body.classList.add("style1");
  body.classList.add("style2");
}
else{
  body.classList.add("style1");
}
```