# How do I get the IP address of the react UI server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ip-address

The app I am working on has a UI written in reactJS. The UI is hosted on (say) ui.mydomain.local and the backend is hosted on (say) app.mydomain.local. Both are ALWAYS hosted on the same domain. There is a config file in the UI build that contains the backend server ip. The UI uses the config file to makes a javascript call to the backend upon page load to get some data.

We have an issue with regards to deployment. The deployment team wants us to get rid of the config file and they want us to update the UI to compute the server address itself; by appending "app" to the domain on which ui is hosted.

Is this possible?

Comment: Simple enough to parse `window.location.origin` in front end to switch out the subdomain values

Comment: Maybe this can also help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/37330947/6121888

Comment: Well yes it's possible, and also much more standard. When doing HTTP requests from a webapp, you usually make requests to a domain, rather than a specific IP address. So as @charlietfl mentioned, you could do something like `window.location.origin.replace('ui','app')` to get the domain with `app` instead of `ui`.

Comment: This will solve for my case since the user is unlikely to use an IP address.. But is there a way to solve this if the user used an IP address instead of the domain name?